# Assert failure error when opening chm file

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

I installed xchm but I can't open chm file. It gives the following error. How do I resolve this?

> ../src/common/unichar.cpp(65): assert "Assert failure" failed in ToHi8bit(): character cannot be converted to single byte

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you place the chm file in another directory not include chinese and open again,can it help?